# Can't use WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in a custom spring boot starter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to create my own spring boot starter for my custom security configuration (LDAP + JWT) via defining configuration class which extends from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. However, when I launch my application with this starter I get:

```
IllegalStateException: Found WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as well as SecurityFilterChain.
Please select just one.
```

I found out that it's not possible any longer to do that due to [this issue of the spring security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8804). There is an assertion in WebSecurityConfiguration of the spring:

[image: Snapshot from WebSecurityConfiguration.java]

**I solved this** adding to the starter the following (according to the issue):

```
@Bean
@Order(1) //Explanation for this below
open fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity, jwtHelper: JwtHelper): SecurityFilterChain {
    return http.authorizeRequests()
           ...
               .addFilterBefore(JwtAuthenticationFilter(jwtHelper), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
               .and().build()
}

@Bean
open fun authenticationProvider(ldapConfig: LdapConfig): ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider {
    return ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(...)
}
```

I added `@Order(1)` because there are two `securityFilterChains`: mine (defined in the configurartion above) and another one from an unknown source. I suppose, the latter is the reason of impossibility of using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

### The main problem is that I can't find where that comes from.

Breakpoint from `WebSecurityConfiguration`... just in case:
[image: Break point from WebSecurityConfiguration]

I assume, because of that I can't use `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`
as well. It says:

```
Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer
to already built object
```

---

Here is list of my dependencies:

1. Module with models which is used by the starter (name: my-ldap-security-model):

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core'
    compileOnly 'org.springframework:spring-web'
    compileOnly 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api'
    api 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api'
    api 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime'
    api 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt'
}
```

2. Module with models which is used by the starter (name: my-ldap-security-spring-boot-starter):

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':my-ldap-security-model')
    compileOnly 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api'
    api 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core'
    api 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config'
    api 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web'
    api 'org.springframework:spring-web'
    api 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap'
}
```

3. App project:

```
dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation('com.demo.boot:my-ldap-security-spring-boot-starter:0.0.1')
}
```

### Please, help me find out the root of that filter.

Comment: its spring boot autoconfiguration https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-hello-auto-configuration also i suggest you switch out jjwt for https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#spring-security-oauth2-jose as spring has default support for JOSE.

Comment: also spring boot has default support for jwt with already a built in jwt filter so no need to register your own custom jwt filter. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture which means that if you want to use JWT all you need to to do is to register some beans , and then each application can define what endpoints they want JWT authentication on and they will get your bean. No nead to register a filter and build a custom filter chain.

Answer (score 4):

Initially, the default `SecurityFilterChain` are disabled if there is any `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. However, it doesn't work if the priority of the spring security auto-configuration is higher than auto-configuration with your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

**Solution**: I added `@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 10)` above the auto-configuration class. There is no default security filter chain any longer :)

About `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`... It was about caches. Suddenly, it got fixed.

Answer (score 3):

For googlers

You can't use

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http)...
```

while extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Either choose above one or only override

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at project structure, there might be a securityFilterChain coming from xml configuration rather than class extension. XML with http tag.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved same error by changing order of servlets in web.xml.
↓ no problem order xxx -> yyy 〇  　yyy -> xxx ×

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>xxxServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   … ommit
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>xxxServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet> 
    <servlet-name>yyyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   … ommit
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>yyyServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/yyy/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```